# Why the stereo mp3 file lost a channel when converted from mp4 with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I am following this tutorial https://hackernoon.com/audio-handling-basics-how-to-process-audio-files-using-python-cli-jo283u3y, and when I extract the data from the mp3 file, it is only an one dimensional array, while the data from wav file is 2D. I converted them from the same mp4 file with ffmpeg.

```
# read WAV file using scipy.io.wavfile
fs_wav, data_wav = wavfile.read("data/music_8k.wav")

# read MP3 file using pydub
audiofile = AudioSegment.from_file("data/music_8k.mp3")
data_mp3 = np.array(audiofile.get_array_of_samples())
fs_mp3 = audiofile.frame_rate

print(data_wav.shape) #(9835520, 2)
print(fs_wav) #44100
print(data_mp3.shape) #(19671040,)
print(fs_mp3) #44100
```

When I check the info of the mp3 file it says Stereo, but does the fact that `data_mp3` is only one dimensional array mean it is actually mono? Did it lose one channel during converting? And how should I reshape the data if I want to confirm these two files have identical signal?

Answer (score 1):

> but does the fact that data_mp3 is only one dimensional array mean it is actually mono?

No.

> And how should I reshape the data if I want to confirm these two files have identical signal?

Decode it back to a wav